# Permission Problems for copied files from NAS

Tags: network, permission, filesystem, nas, afp

I access my Synology NAS via AFP and can open/edit all of my files directly on it. But when I copy a file to my desktop I can't open it. Finder tells me I don't have appropriate permissions.

When I look at the permissions (CMD + I) on …

#### … my NAS:

- (unknown): read & write
- everyone: no permissions

#### … my desktop:

- staff: read & write
- everyone: no permissions

ls -l will print (for both paces): ----rwx---  1 suntrop  staff  35354  4 Jul 10:32 File.docx

Is this a problem on the Mac or Synology or my settings?

Comment: The permissions should ideally be 755, i.e., rwxr-xr-x at both places.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And what causes the problem or how to avoid it? :-)

Comment: I don’t know what caused the problem or how to avoid it, but you can probably fix it by running `sudo chmod -R 755 /path/to/drive` in the Terminal. That’s why I didn’t put this as an answer.

Comment: That's not only this particular file. Almost all files have this problem. anyway, I'll check some other resources and try to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: No, I did not say `path/to/file`, I said `path/to/drive`. This will fix ALL files on the drive.

Comment: Do you know why it's possible to change the permissions? It seems I don't have them (since I cannot open the files), but can change permissions. Shouldn't permissions prevent it?

Comment: That’s because you are using `sudo`. This command gives you `superuser` privileges. The superuser can do anything.

Comment: I can change chmod without sudo – even now, if I haven't logged in as sudo.

Comment: Well I don’t know how that happened.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a permission problem. I had a similar issue. Files created by one user in two groups (*administrator* & *user*) on NAS were not being able to read by users only in the *user* group. I tried reseting ownership/permissions using File Station from DiskStation and did nothing. I figured something was wrong with root folder permissions on shared folder - and yes, they were owned by root and 777 chmod.

I've managed to fix this by:

1. On the Synology - control panel - win/mac/nfs - goto Mac File Serivce (AFP) and turn off Apply default UNIX permissions (Mac file services enabled) - root of your problem
2. log on to NAS via ssh, go to most root shared folder and do

   ```
   chown -R nobody:users shared_folder/
   chmod -R 755 shared_folder/
   ```

used info from [here](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=52682), [here](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=76338) and [here](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=69504).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I discovered that if I close the folder in the finder there's no problem with permissions. If the folder is open and displayed, then I get the message that I can't save my file due to the fact that I don't have the necessary permissions. Go figure, but it works here every time.

Answer (score -2):

Do not connect via AFP: use SMB.

Comment: Why should they connect via SMB instead of AFP? While this might be exactly right, some more explanation would be nice.

Comment: Although SMB will work it doesn't support some of the OS X features I like. I submitted a bug report to Apple and – I hope – they fix it :-)

Comment: Synology had to reverse engineer AFP, whereas SMB is open source. That's why SMB is safer to use, especially with newer OS X versions